# how to groupby items List<keyvaluepair <string,datetime[]>> over date

Tags: c#, list, count, fill

I have a datatable filled by date , day ,name and type so I read from this datatable into List> using C#.net so 
the code is this :

```
 dicArray = dtrd.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(Row => Row["IDp"]).Distinct()
    .Select(Id => new KeyValuePair<string, string[]>(
        Id.ToString(),
        dtrd.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(Row => Row["IDp"].ToString() == Id.ToString())
            .Select(Row => Row["date"].ToString()+";"+ Row["day"].ToString()+";"+Row["nobatkari"].ToString() + ";" + Row["pname"].ToString())
            .ToArray()))
    .ToList();
```

now I want to count each item over date I mean that I want to know how many rows are with the same date
please help me to solve it

for example:

```
1   **2017-02-19** 15:12:20 1   0   1   0
1   **2017-02-19** 15:12:37 1   0   1   0
1   **2017-02-19** 15:12:41 1   0   1   0  Count:3
1   **2017-02-20** 15:14:10 1   2   1   0
1   **2017-02-20** 16:38:14 1   2   1   0
3   **2017-02-20** 16:38:19 1   2   1   0   Count:3
3   **2017-02-21** 16:39:09 1   0   1   0
3   **2017-02-21** 17:25:06 1   0   1   0
2   **2017-02-21** 18:28:50 1   0   1   0   Count:3
2   **2017-02-22** 18:29:04 1   0   1   0   Count:1
2   **2017-02-23** 18:29:17 1   0   1   0
3   **2017-02-23** 18:30:45 1   0   1   0   Count:2
2   **2017-02-24** 18:31:32 1   0   1   0
2   **2017-02-24** 18:31:47 1   0   1   0   Count:2
2   **2017-02-25** 18:32:18 1   4   1   0   Count:1
```

Of course I want date section not time include

Comment: If you need date only means,                                                                                                                                                                              var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = dateAndTime.Date;

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = yourList.GroupBy(x => x.date.Date).Select(x=> new { date = x.Key, count = x.Count() });
```

This will create a new list containtng date and count of elements for each date.

Comment: Aha, i see where is problem now. My code is working on list without conversion to keyvaluepair. Try this dt.AsEnumerable().ToList().GroupBy(x => x.date.Date).Select(x=> new { date = x.Key, count = x.Count() });